# How to invert touchpad scrolling on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 and would like to invert my touchpad scrolling so that moving my two fingers towards the monitor causes the screen to scroll up. Previously, there used to be an option in mouse and touchpad settings that allowed for this. Similarly, `gsettings` indicates that touchpad configurations are deprecated. Thoughts?

Edit: the xinput command gives this output:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]  
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]  
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]  
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys                     id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]  
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

For some reason, I don't see a trackpad listed. I'm on a Dell Latitude E5570 laptop that definitely has a trackpad. Additionally, no mouse and trackpad options appear to support the trackpad.

Also, looking at the directory `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, I only see these configuration files:

```
10-amdgpu.conf  
10-evdev.conf  
10-quirks.conf  
11-evdev-quirks.conf      
11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  
50-synaptics.conf  
50-vmmouse.conf               
50-wacom.conf  
51-synaptics-quirks.conf
```

Comment: Are you using `xorg-synaptics` or `libinput`?

Comment: I appear to have packages for both installed. I'm not sure how to check which are in use. I'm running a fairly clean 16.04 install, so I doubt I've changed the default.

Comment: `libinput` is not installed, so it is not an issue. It looks like your touchpad is not supported.  Does scrolling work at all?

Comment: Yep, two finger scrolling works as you'd expect it. It's a fully functional trackpad.

Comment: It is weird.  It is detected as a mouse. Do you have a mouse attached?

Comment: If you don't have a mouse attached, add output of `xinput list-props 14`

Comment: I have an external mouse connected via a docking station, but I disconnected that before I ran my commands. There is also an inset pointing stick mouse in the keyboard.

Comment: You can use a 3rd party program as in the duplicate link, or you can do it manually, but it is not that simple.

Answer (score 28):

The option to invert scrolling directions is called **Natural Scrolling** and is still present in 16.04's **System Settings → Mouse & Touchpad** configuration.

[image]

Comment: With libinput this option is not there.

Comment: I used this setting a week ago. This morning scrolling no longer works and this option is gone. Was there an update released changing this?

Comment: @Mika No idea, I'm not aware of any updates regarding this. For me it still looks the same (running 16.04)

Comment: I have no idea what happened but I managed to solve it by deleting my .config folder. After a reboot, the option reappeared and things are working now. Strange. If anyone else has this issue, please remember that deleting .config folder will remove ALL your settings...

Comment: Moving my `~/.config/` folder and rebooting did not work for me on Ubuntu 16.04. There is no Natural scrolling option when you have a mouse.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `libinput`, the GUI options are not available.

In this case you can enable "Natural Scrolling" by adding

```
Option  "NaturalScrolling" "True"
```

to the touchpad section of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput.conf` file.

Comment: That config file didn't actually exist for me. I assume that it had a nontrivial format, so I didn't go ahead and try to create it . I posted that directory's contents in my edit.

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 22.04 with Unity, except the file was called `40-libinput.conf`.  Also, need to log out and in to see changes

Answer (score 6):

If you use `libinput`, then add a config file to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` such as `20-touchpad.conf` with this content:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"

        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
EndSection
```

There are other useful features such as:

```
        Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
        Option "Tapping" "on"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
```

If you like, this can also be enabled for any mice with the following content in `30-pointer.conf`

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"

        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
EndSection
```

More info `man libinput`.

Comment: For me on Ubuntu 20.04 with Unity, the file to edit was called `40-libinput.conf`, not `20-touchpad.conf`.

Answer (score 2):

If you install the `touchpad-indicator` using Synaptic, it has a `natural scrolling` option.

Start Synaptic from the dashboard, click the RELOAD icon, then type `touchpad` into the search box. Then mark the `touchpad-indicator` for install, then click the APPLY icon.

Let us know how you do. Cheers, Al