# How to install gnome desktop in ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: gnome, 17.04

How to install gnome desktop in ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: Check out http://ubuntugnome.org/.

Comment: But you'd better read my own question/answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/903373/unity-problems-after-installing-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: Why so many downvotes for this answer. My thoughts exactly @nazar2sfive well done! If we are going to forget Unity let's get rid of it now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you already have an existing Ubuntu installation with another or no desktop environment, open a terminal and enter the following:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: Is this going o remove unity? or what. Would I have option to choose on login which desktop environment will I use or how do I use gnome? What is the visual difference? Is gnome better supported? Is computer going to be faster? Is resource usage going to be lower? I have so many questions please someone help with answering them.

Comment: @luka Then please do some research and [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) if needed. You could also try running the command in an Ubuntu VM, if you want to test it for yourself.

Comment: @Luka I'm not sure why they didn't answer your question, after doing the install you should notice a change immediately. When you boot your machine you'll see a new logo and ideally during the install you'll select `gdm3` (the gnome display manager) instead of (`lightdm`) the ubuntu native option. When I did my own install I could only boot with gdm3 as the default. lmk if you have other questions.

Comment: Did you notice any speed improvements? Lower resource usage?

Comment: I needed to install more packages `sudo apt install metacity gnome-core gnome-panel` before I was able to see a usual gnome UI.