# Is there a way to seamlessly switch desktop environments?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, kubuntu, kde, desktop-environments

I'm using Kubuntu 22 LTS and I'm tired of the KDE desktop environment. I wanna switch to gnome and have the Ubuntu experience. I don't have much data on my hard drive and i have not made a seperate partition for my home directory.

Questions -

- Can I switch to a different desktop environment **seamlessly** without losing data?
- Can I swap Kubuntu with Ubuntu (losing data is fine in this case)?
- If swapping desktop environments is possible seamlessly, does it apply to Xubuntu, Lubuntu, MATE and other Ubuntu flavours?

Comment: You can always install another DE. But the problem is that packages from the old one will stay.

Comment: Yes & No.   I'm a lover of multiple desktops, but be aware the Ubuntu Core 22 (or any *specialist* release using the 22 or *year* format) is a server only intended product; you should be using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS instead (which can be used by server & desktop systems unlike 22 products).  22 != 22.04 as it's a different Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2):

Different desktops can be installed together, but that can come with some issues, in particular where your application menu will be overpopulated with applications from the different desktop environments with duplicate functionality.

> Can I switch to a different desktop environment seamlessly without losing data?

As indicated, one can install multiple desktop environments. "Seamless" is a subjective term. If you mean by that "without effort", then yes: it is a matter of a single apt command and then logging in to the new desktop. If, by "seamless", you mean ending up on a system as if only that other desktop was installed, then the answer is: that is more difficult, and will require some manual reconfiguration and removal of packages.

To quantitatively remove the desktop of the Ubuntu version you installed, is difficult. However, if you take note of all of the packages that are installed when you install another desktop, you will later on be able to quantitatively remove them again.

> Can I swap kUbuntu with Ubuntu (losing data is fine in this case)?

Not sure why you doubt about this. It is a matter of grabbing the Ubunt installation medium, doing an install overwriting your current linux install, and then putting your data back. Probably the easiest way for a "seamless" transition in the second meaning of the word.

> If swapping desktop environments is possible seamlessly, does it apply to Xubuntu, Lubuntu, MATE and other Ubuntu flavours?

Again, in the second sense of the word, it is a matter of reinstalling with the corresponding installation medium. In the first sense of the word, you can install multiple desktop environments, have them all installed simultaneously, and log in to any of them any time. The only caveat here is that you need to take note of the installed packages if you later want to remove a desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

Makulu Linux Switch can do this. It comes with 8 different Desktop Environments. So it must be possible. I don't know how they did this though. 
But you can install 'gnome-desktop' on Kubuntu. When logging in there should be a gear icon where you can choose between KDE- and Gnome-desktop. You won't loose any data installing the DE.
You need to log out to change DE's, by clicking the gear and choose desired DE, and log in again.
gnome shell - https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell 
ubuntu desktop https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop
edit 220428-0904:
See [What is the difference between Ubuntu GNOME and Gnome Desktop or just installing Gnome Shell on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958824/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-gnome-and-gnome-desktop-or-just-installing) for more information.

Comment: Why not `ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: gnome-shell will install the minimal packages for gnome-shell. ubuntu-desktop will install gnome-shell + additional desktop apps + ubuntu themes. For details see the packages.