# Super hotkeys not working properly (randomly opening dash)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, unity-dash, workspaces

I am using ubuntu 18.04, and I am using hotkeys to switch workspaces and move windows around workspaces. The hotkeys I am using are '[Super]1-9' for switching and '[Super][Shift]1-9' for moving windows around. Most of the time this works perfectly fine.

However, every now and then the dash shows up and the hotkey isn't working anymore ([Dash hotkey icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYwP.png)). This can happen for any hotkey and most of the time only one hotkey isn't working. So for example what could happen: '[Super]1' and '[Super]3' are working fine and are switching workspaces, but '[Super]2' will not switch and will only open the dash and show number for every application in the dash ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDYwP.png)). The weird thing is that which hotkey isn't working seems random, and most of the time only one isn't working.

Comment: There is a bug report on short cut keys not working this could be related.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Additional Layout Options" under keyboard settings in the Gnome Tweak Tool (as per [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924472/superkey-not-registering-in-gnome-17-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)? The question was about 17.10 but I saw [another related question](https://tinyurl.com/y8qosl3l) for 18.04 that also suggested using Tweak...in this case, the OP had a different problem, where the right super key didn't work)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Also it seems like [Super]1-9 is also used as switching (or opening) to the app at that number in the dash. However, I cant find this hotkey or a way to disable it.

Comment: I solved it now, it was because of the `dash-to-dock` shell extension, which was still triggering hotkeys even though I removed the extension. So, now I just set the hotkeys to [] (i.e. nothing) in the dconf editor.