# Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 problems now that I've switched full time

Tags: gnome, 17.04, gdm

I was running Ubuntu Unity 17.04, and I decided to install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` so I could start playing with GNOME ahead of the release of 17.10 where it becomes the default desktop environment.

In the Unity desktop environment, this initially broke some stuff, as evidenced by my question at [Unity problems after installing GNOME desktop (ubuntu-gnome-desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903373/unity-problems-after-installing-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-desktop). Most of these problems were resolved.

Like Unity, I originally used LightDM as the display manager for GNOME. Now I've switched to the gdm3 display manager, and GNOME full time, I've got new problems...

- I can no longer switch between GNOME and Unity desktop environments at the login screen.
- I can no longer log into the root account.
- I can no longer log into the guest account.
- I can no longer get to the text tty by typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> .. <kbd>F6</kbd>).

I assume that if I switch back to the LightDM display manager, that these problems will revert, but I'd like to get these problems addressed with the gdm3 display manager.

Any ideas or work arounds?

Comment: I've read lots of discussion about this topic on Ubuntu Desktop; its been fixed for 17.10 (with very-few very-minor exceptions), but I don't recall mention of any attempts to work on 17.04.  I only scan-read the initial paragraphs of each ubuntu-desktop post so I can't offer any advice

Comment: Just a comment... I'm staying on 16.04 until 18 comes out. This whole transition from Unity to Gnome will take time to work out and although leading-edge technology is great I don't want to be on the bleeding-edge. I still read threads like this with interest and appreciate your pioneering.

Comment: @guiverc can you please tell me the web site/page  to visit so that I can read what you've been reading? Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema oh I do run 16.04.2 and the newer kernels 4.4.0-78, 4.4.0-79 & 4.4.0-81 are auto installed along with 4.11.1 & 4.11.3 manually installed.

Comment: @heynnema To install the newest kernels I follow this technique: https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version/879920#879920 I don't think this as bleeding edge like the switch from 14.04 to 16.04 which cost weeks of time in suspend/resume, pulse audio, laptop overheating, High DPI and font issues, etc. etc.

Comment: @heynnema   much of what I read is feeds read via my liferea rss reader which is many.  I suspect though I was talking about stuff on the ubuntu-desktop [mailing list], or at least weekly-reports by Will Cooke (ubuntu-desktop team head).  I'm involved with ubuntu-weekly-newsletter `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter` so a small % of what I read makes into that  (i collect the links).  if after a single link, the UWN link is where to grab it (sources I use would get it quicker)

Comment: another place to look is `http://planet.ubuntu.com/`  which is a major source I read via liferea (gnome RSS reader).  its a common source for most distros as many projects, distros run the software (which scrapes listed sites for new blog-entries etc).  some are listed under different name (eg. 'planet fedora' renamed itself 'fedora people' awhile ago).  if you want to know more about gnome; it'll be 'planet gnome' etc.