# ubuntu gnome OR gnome over ubuntu

Tags: unity, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I am currently using ubuntu 16.04 lts version. i wish to know which one is better choice installing gnome3 as a seperate DE alongside unity or installing ubuntu gnome fresh? is there any difference among them performance-wise or, version-wise or, stability-wise?

i did once use gnome 3.18 , but there were glitches like unresponsive applications menu!do such problems occur often in gnome 3?

if install gnome 3 in standard ubuntu release, will it be a official gnome package?

lastly, since ubuntu will switch over to gnome from 2018, will the release be as stable as unity 7 ?

Comment: I've been using Ubuntu-Gnome since 14.04, and have not experienced stability issues.  In the earlier releases, I did use the updated gnome packages from the [gnome3-team](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3?field.series_filter=zesty) but I have not found those necessary with Zesty.

Comment: What criteria should be considered to judge 'better'?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

You ask about two choices:

1. install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` on top of an existing Unity installation
2. install `Ubuntu GNOME` fresh

If you're thinking about option #1, which is what I opted to do, you should read my question and answer at [Unity problems after installing GNOME desktop (ubuntu-gnome-desktop)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903373/unity-problems-after-installing-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-desktop) as it'll save you a lot of time.

Once I installed GNOME (and used lighdm as my display manager) on my system, I remained primarily in Unity, and used GNOME as a learning environment. I've more recently switched full time to GNOME, and have changed my display manager from lightdm to gdm3, and undone some of the things answered in my earlier question.

Option #2 will probably be the most reliable, long term, if you have backups for your data.