# Ubuntu 16.04 wifi stop working after unity 8

Tags: wireless, unity

I have tried to install unity 8 on my ubuntu 16.04 following this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/04/ubuntu-16-04-unity-8-desktop-progress-video)

after installing I tried to use unity 8 and it ended in a black screen, nothing was being displayed, so that I have restart my Ubuntu and logged in on default unity (7.4) so my wifi is not working anymore, I have changed to my windows 10 on dual boot and the wifi on windows is not working too... I am googling a lot and I can't find a fix for that, anyone could help?

I have already tried `sudo systemctl restart network-manager` but it doesn't work

**hardware information of my notebook lenovo ideapad 310 15ISK 80UH:**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 134f (rev a2)
```

**lspci command result:**

```
~  $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; rfkill list
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: If it doesn't work in both OSes, it is *not* a Ubuntu issue and certainly not related with the attempt to use another desktop environment. It's either a coincidence that the hardware became defective (or in need of reseating) when you were experimenting or something else happened and you're not telling us... Perhaps you inadvertently switched off the WiFi?

Comment: my wifi is enabled on bios, I am a programmer so I know at least the basics xD the only thing I did was installing unity 8, its very odd...

Comment: Please [edit] and include the hardware information. Check with `lspci`(for internal WiFi cards). If you can't see it there then it's defective or dislodged (yes, it happens). In that case remove and reinsert it and it should work right away in both. And it can be enabled in BIOS/UEFI and yet switched off by a special key or some FN+Fx.

Comment: @MichaelBay thanks, I added the hardware information, there is a ethernet controller but no wireless controller... is that the point? I'm on a notebook it can be fried? I bought this notebook 6 months ago and the wifi stopped working when I installed unity 8, it's odd... ://

Comment: Yes, it should be there regardless of blocks. Really not good but the first thing to try is re-seat the card (you may want to check a couple of videos if you haven't done that before).

Comment: Unity 8 is at best an alpha quality piece of software. It's no longer developed or supported. Don't bother installing it... too late I guess. I'd troubleshoot the wireless problem from Windows first. Once you get it working there it may very well work in Ubuntu.

Comment: @heynnema do you know any other interface that is beautiful as unity 8 and don't broke my ubuntu?

Comment: @WagnerMoreira since GNOME is Ubuntu's future, starting in October, I'd install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`and that will give you a head start. You might try uninstalling/purging Unity 8 first and see what's left.

Comment: @heynnema by installing gnome desktop there is any chance of broke my unity?

Comment: If you're primarily going to use GNOME, no problem. If you're primarily going to stick with Unity, you should read my question/answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/903373/unity-problems-after-installing-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-desktop for some good information.

Comment: @heynnema I'm with gnome shell now and I liked it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling wireless card, thanks to @MichaelBay