# How do I change The Ubuntu display manager back to lightdm

Tags: boot, plymouth

As I was trying to solve desktop-icon problems though terminal, I came to the choice between `lightdm` and `gdm3`. Not knowing what either of them were, I selected `gdm3`.

It loaded a good amount of code, and I noticed it went though all of the same processes that `sudo update-grub` would. The next time the computer rebooted, the boot went fine, but it looked a lot different. [Here is the new display manager logo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxRIh.jpg) This logo shows up on start-up and shutdown. How do I get Ubuntu's display manager back to what it was?

I've since switched the desktop display manager back to `lightdm` successfully, but I can't figure out how to change too boot display manager back too.

My main concern is about reinstalling ubuntu. Since the display manager is different, a live Ubuntu USB does not recognise Ubuntu as its own operating system and thus will not "reinstall."

I'm sure the answer is very simple, but being fairly new to Ubuntu, I need some help. Indeed, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but just so you know, lightdm and gdm are not boot loaders.  Bootloading happens way before these programs run.  These programs are display managers (hence the dm in their names) and do just that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LightDM

Comment: Please see https://askubuntu.com/questions/903373/unity-problems-after-installing-gnome-desktop-ubuntu-gnome-desktop. Please remember to vote for it if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`, then pick a theme.

You will need to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to see the change.

*(Edit: It's replacing the shutdown theme just fine, but not the startup theme.)*