# libinput: How to properly set up trackpads to inverse scroll in 16.04 and onward for Logitech wireless keyboards + trackpads?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, logitech, libinput

I found a real nice answer here that would be great if it worked:
https://askubuntu.com/a/820098/134500

I'd like to use `libinput` to get scrolling to work properly as well as other trackpad and pointing functionality. When I attempt to enable it, unfortunately the keyboard + trackpad ([Logitech K400+](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400-plus)) entirely stops working.

Under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` I have:

**20-touchpad.conf:**

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"

        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
        Option "MiddleEmulation" "on"
        Option "Tapping" "off"
        Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
EndSection
```

**30-pointer.conf**

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"

        Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
EndSection
```

I thought that `libinput` was already active on 16.04, however, as noted, input for the keyboard stops altogether. I'm not seeing an issue in the logs. Any thoughts on how to ensure that `libinput` is working and on how to get it to work with this Logitech K400+?

Perhaps `libinput` is Wayland only and since this is running xorg this is the dilema in this instance? If so, what's the right approach here?